# ¿Como pasar por parámetro una función lambda en Java?

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

Quiero pasar por parametro una funcion lambda en java
Ej:

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    foo((int value) -> {
        System.out.println(value);
    });
}

public static void foo(function callback) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        callback(i);
    }
}
```

Y el resulta es :

```
0
1
2
3
...
...
9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ver, las lambdas lo que hacen es definir la implementación de una **interface funcional**.

Una interface funcional es una interface que se caracteriza porque solo tiene un único método que no deriva de `Object`, por ejemplo

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface MiInterface {
   public boolean equals(Object object);
   public void imprimir(int value);
}
```

Es una interface funcional. El `@FunctionalInterface` es opcional pero ayuda a que el compilador te avise si resulta que no cumple los requisitos; `equals` no cuenta porque está definido en `java.lang.Object`.

Como solo necesitas implementar un método, cuando tienes una lambda está claro qué método está implementando esa lambda. Y puedes hacer

```
MiInterface miFuncion = value -> System.out.println(value);
```

De la misma manera, puedes definir

```
public static void foo(MiInterface callback) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      callback.imprimir(i);
   }
}
```

Java ya proporciona un conjunto de interfaces funcionales estándar para este tipo de asignaciones (de forma que normalment no tendrás que definir `MiInterface`); por ejemplo una interfaz con un método que toma un valor pero no devuelve nada es un [`java.util.function.Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

```
public static void foo(Consumer<Integer> callback) {
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      callback.accept(i);
   }
}
```

Puedes mirar [la documentación del package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) para familiarizarte con los tipos ofrecidos.

Comment: Gracias @SJuan76 me es muy util, tu respuesta